# semantic-release breaking-change using ! (exclamation mark)

Tags: semantic-release, conventional-commits, conventional-changelog

Can Major version changes (aka Breaking Changes) be handled in [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) using the exclamation mark?

```sh
git commit -m 'feat!: this is breaking, but is not recognized by semantic-release'
```

Conventional Commit guidelines show that breaking changes can be labeled in the footer in using an exclamation mark in the header.

[image]

This is the workflow that I have been testing

### Setup repository ✓

```sh
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:klueless-io/k_genesis.git
git branch -M main
git add .
git commit -am 'first commit'
# Artificial starting version number
git tag v0.0.18 -a -m 'k_genesis initialize repository'
git push -u origin main --tags
git hist
```

[image]

### Remove a single file and call it a new feature ✓

```sh
rm a1
git add .
git commit -m 'feat: remove a1'
git hist
```

[image]

```sh
npx semantic-release --no-ci
```

[image]

```
git hist
```

[image]

### Now Breaking Change using Footer Message ✓

> This does not work as expected

```
rm a2
git add .
git commit -m 'feat: removed a2   

BREAKING CHANGE: break dancing
'
git hist
```

[image]

```sh
npx semantic-release --no-ci
```

[image]

### Looking Good So Far ✓

[image]

### Now try a breaking change using ! exclamation mark ✗ :( :( :(

```sh
rm a3
git add .
git commit -m 'feat!: removed a3 with exclamation in header'
```

[image]

```sh
npx semantic-release --no-ci
# Analysis of 1 commits complete: no release
```

[image]

```
git hist
```

[image]

```sh
touch xmen
git add .
git commit -m 'feat: normal feat'
npx semantic-release --no-ci
git hist
```

[image]

### Attempted custom configurations

I have used the default preset for "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer" (**angular**) and I have tried a custom preset (**conventionalcommits**)

[my .releaserc](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klueless-io/k_genesis/main/.releaserc)

```js
{
  "branches": [
    "main"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer", {
      "preset": "conventionalcommits"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Looking a the source code

When I looked at the source code [conventional-changelog-conventionalcommits](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-changelog/blob/master/packages/conventional-changelog-conventionalcommits/parser-opts.js) it seamed like breaking change in header should be supported.

[image]

Comment: This has recently stopped working for me as well. I have the following config, this used to work:

const parserOpts = {
    noteKeywords: ['BREAKING-CHANGE', 'BREAKING CHANGE', 'BREAKING CHANGES'],
    headerPattern: /^(\w*)(?:\(([\w\$\.\-\* ]*)\))?!?: (.*)$/,
    breakingHeaderPattern: /^(\w*)(?:\((.*)\))?!: (.*)$/,
};

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually configure it in `.releaserc`:

YAML

```yaml
branches:
  - main
plugins:
  - - "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
    - preset: conventionalcommits
      releaseRules:
        - type: '*!'
          release: major
```

JSON

```json
{
  "branches": [
    "main"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
      {
        "preset": "conventionalcommits",
        "releaseRules": [
          {
            "type": "*!",
            "release": "major"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: `["@semantic-release/commit-analyzer", { "preset": "conventionalcommits" }]]`
should be enough as the exclamation mark is already configured in the preset, no?